# Specifying additional conditional compilation symbols via devenv for a C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devenv

I'm trying to pass an additional conditional compilation symbol via devenv (vs2010) on the command line to the C# compiler.

I know it can be done for the C++ compiler through the [CL environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kezkeayy.aspx). 
Is there something similar possible for C#?

Since this build pass needs to run Code Analysis, I'm stuck with using devenv to launch the build, as far as I know.

Comment: Not with devenv.exe.  You can with MSBuild, /property option to *replace* the `<DefineConstants>` property, not add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify any compilation symbols via the command line to `devenv.exe` but you can create a separate solution configuration and refer to it in the command line:

```
devenv.exe SolutionName /build SolnConfigName
```

Answer (score 0):

In the project settings under build there is a setting "symbols for conditional compilation", at least in vs2008, but I think vs2010 wilkl provide similar.

Comment: Yup - and I'd like to control that via the command line of devenv.